# C++ General Performance Difference between Compilers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction

I recently started learning C++, and I can now write and run basic c++ programs myself..

One thing I don't understand, however, is why run speeds differ so much in different compilers..

For instance, I have this block of code:

```
class MyObject {
public:
    MyObject(string Str) : m_Str(Str) { }

    string m_Str;
};




int main() {

    chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> tstart = chrono::system_clock::now();

    vector<MyObject> VectorOfObjects;
    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        MyObject x("test");
        VectorOfObjects.push_back(x);
    }

    chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> tend = chrono::system_clock::now();

    chrono::duration<double> tt = tend-tstart;
    cout << "Execution Time: " << tt.count()*1000 << " Milliseconds\n" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Now when I built and ran this code in Visual Studio 2012, the result printed:

```
Execution Time: 989 Milliseconds
```

But then, when I compile and run the exact same code in Ideone ([Link](http://ideone.com/THgDQA)) ,

The result is only

```
Execution Time: 1.65675 Milliseconds
```

So basically, Running in Visual Studio is almost 1000 times slower!!!

As a newbie in programming, I don't understand why there has to be such a huge difference in speed.

So my question is,

What is the cause of this difference??

Also, if this is caused by different compiler settings,,, how do I view and change this in Visual Studio..?

Thanks

Comment: By the way, the proper way to get milliseconds is `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tend - tstart).count()`. Anyway, your VS compiler options are in your project settings.

Comment: You need to make sure you are making a release build on VS. If you are building debug, then there are all kinds of reasons why it will be very slow.

Comment: This depend of various factors, used compiler (what capability has, C++11, optimization implemented, auto-vectorization, etc...), compilers options (optimizations flags, debug, release, etc...), most probably in your case, you are compiling in VS2012 in debug and Ideone is compiling release.

Comment: Did you get the shareware version of MSVS? Clearly there's going to be a competitive difference between the shareware and the professional version, otherwise nobody would buy it.